# Wildfly 10 hibernate properties being shared among multiple applications

Tags: hibernate, wildfly

We have two independent applications App1 and App2 deployed on wildfly 10 server(as separate .war files) and both using the 'org.hibernate' module from wildfly. Ideally, both application should be connecting to two separate databases.

Each of these applications has its own hibernate.properties within their respective classpaths.

**Issue**

The first application App1 to be deployed is configured correctly to use the database, but the second application App2 when deployed, uses the hibernate properties from the first application and thus connects to App1's DB.

It seems, wildfly initializes the hibernate module with the first hibernate.properties found and uses it with all the other applications deployed on the server.

Any suggestion on how both applications can be configured to connect to its own DB or any pointers on how the hibernate module loading works for multiple applications in wildfly would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Wildfly you are not supposed to use Hibernate directly. Instead you should use the JPA-API as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide).

This means that you are using the `EntityManager` that is injected into your code:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "customerPU")
EntityManager em;
```

The value for `unitName` references the name of the data source configured in your standalone.xml. If you are not using dependency injection, then you can also bind the `EntityManager` to a JNDI entry, as explained [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-BindingEntityManagerFactory%2FEntityManagertoJNDI).

Hence you can define two different data sources in your standalone.xml and inject in both applications two different entity managers.

Comment: Thanks siom for the hint. Let me try it out.